# How to Hide Posts and Pages in the WordPress Admin Panel from other admin

Tags: wordpress

how to hide post from other admin/user? 
for example in my blog have 3 admin. 
i called admin1 and admin2 and my username is wpadmin..
how to hide wpadmin post/page from admin1 and admin2...
i have a code..
but is not a simple ...
my code needed add manually post id / page id..

```
//HIDE POST

add_action('admin_head', 'hide_posts_pages');

function hide_posts_pages() {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    If($current_user->user_login != 'wpadmin') {
        ?>
        <style>
           #post-7, {
                display:none;
           }
        </style>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function remove_menus() 
{
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  if($current_user->user_login != 'wpadmin')
  {
     remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );                   //Posts
     remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );    //Pages
   }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```

try this function 
put above code in your active theme **functions.php** file

Comment: get_currentuserinfo is deprecated since version 4.5.0. I replaced is with  wp_get_current_user() and it works just fine. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simply hide via css:

```
// function.php
// Hide posts and comments

add_action('admin_head', 'custom_backend_css');

function custom_backend_css() {
  echo '<style>
           #menu-posts, #menu-comments{
               display: none !important;
           }
        </style>';
}
```